# setting multiple destination files for multiple input files - sortBam

Tags: r, bioinformatics

As a preface, I'm quite new to using R.

I'm dealing with the package Rsamtools, and i'm trying to sort  bam files. I am using the sortBam() command, which requires the following information:

```
sortBam(file, destination, ...).
```

I have an R-object containing the 5 bamfiles:

```
bamfiles <- list.files(fileDir, pattern = "\\.bam", full.names = TRUE)
```

where fileDir = object containing file path.

What I don't know how to do is set the destination file so each of the 5 un-sorted bam files get their own output file. E.g. file1.bam --> file1.sorted.bam ... file5.bam --> file5.sorted.bam. I've been searching around and haven't found (or been aware) of the answer, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have 3 bam files in three different directories.

```
bams <- list.files(".", patter="*.bam", full=T, recur=T)
bams
# [1] "./d1/100.bam" "./d2/11.bam"  "./d3/28.bam"
```

As `sortBam` can only sort one bam file for one time, you can use `for` to loop over the three bam files.

First, set proper destinations.

```
des <- gsub("bam", "sorted", bams)
des
# [1] "./d1/100.sorted" "./d2/11.sorted"  "./d3/28.sorted"
```

The sort part:

```
for (i in 1:length(bams)) {
  sortBam(bams[i], des[i])
}
```

The result files on the disk.

```
ll -htr *
d1:
total 72K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 35K Apr  8  2016 100.bam
-rw-rw-r-- 1 35K Apr  8  2016 100.sorted.bam

d2:
total 64K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 30K Apr  8  2016 11.bam
-rw-rw-r-- 1 31K Apr  8  2016 11.sorted.bam

d3:
total 80K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 40K Apr  8  2016 28.bam
-rw-rw-r-- 1 40K Apr  8  2016 28.sorted.bam
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 

This has sorted out my problem. I was curious about whether sortBam could be used on multiple files at the same time, so that's good to find out also.